# A page jumping bug in Data Explorer's Help section

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, data-explorer, help-center

In Data Explorer's [Help section](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) there are (inside) page jumping link at the right side. E.g. *Getting Started*, *Query Parameters* etc. All links work fine except *Graphing*. It is [linked fine](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#graphing) but the `id` of this section is incorrect. That's why link to *Graphing* doesn't work.

At present it is:

```
<h2 id="#graphing">Graphing</h2>
```

Which should be (just remove `#`):

```
<h2 id="graphing">Graphing</h2>
```

It is a little bug but worth to amend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, whoops, that was my mistake, good catch. [Fixed now](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/15), pending a pull and redeploy of Data Explorer.